# Prononciation du mot "hauteur"

Tags: prononciation

Est-ce qu'on prononce "hauteur" et "auteur" de la même façon? D'une manière générale, comment peut-on savoir si on doit prononcer le "h" ou non et si on doit mettre "l'" avant un mot commençant par "h" ou non?

Comment: Oui, ce sont des  homophones.

Comment: je ne suis pas sûr que les réponses de l'autre question répondent à celle-ci.

Comment: La question porte ici sur la prononciation de hauteur ou auteur et en effet elles sont identiques. Il y a l'autre partie de la question: comment savoir s'il faut la/le ou l' devant tel ou tel mot commençant par h, en dehors de la règle du h muet ou aspiré. Comment savoir si tel h est muet ou aspiré? Y a-t-il une règle ou doit-on mémoriser les différentes occurrences? Je pense que c'est cela la question. Prenons le mot "hure" (féminin); si je ne l'ai jamais rencontré, comment savoir si on dit la hure ou l'hure; je ne peux pas me fier à la règle l' devant h muet et le ou la devant h aspiré...